# Nikon 200-500 f/5.6 Blueprint For DIY LensSkin

Tags: nikon, diy

I'm planning to print my own lens skin similar to [Lens Skins for Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8L USM Zen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007TY2L0M) but in camouflage design on a vinyl sticker sheet. In order to make the cutouts fit perfectly I'd need to know the exact measurements of the lens. However I've failed to find any detail regarding it.

Can someone point me to a lens skin template for blueprint/dimensions for this lens?

Comment: I am a bit naive... Why on earth would someone risk leaving glue on a lens by using that? Well, camouflage has a lot more sense :o)

Comment: No idea, but probably you can take measures and make a dummy made of paper first and see what parts you need.

Comment: There is a lot of supliers and resellers that do that for you, like B&H or Amazon sell those. Anyways I do not understand why anybody will like to do that and made his/her lens loose value whenever you'll sell it. To me is not a nice feature on a lens, but maybe an "excuse" to hide issues on it. If you do really need that camouflage to shoot animals then maybe i'll do that. But otherwise is not cool in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone point me to a lens skin template for blueprint/dimensions for this lens?

No. Consider purchasing calipers.

Comment: If you downvote, does that mean you can? Please write it in an answer.